# Native tablet apps or web app

Tags: web-app, tablet

I am in the initial phase of a project. I have been asked to design a website compatible with tablet. This is more of an application than website.

Users of this application are a niche group who have a purchased a particular service and are tablet users.

I think the Native tablet apps will enhance the user-experience because this app will be used daily and also often. Instead of opening the browser every time in the tablet, an app will be much easier.The user carries his tablet everywhere and so I think there will be no need for a website.

I do not want to get biased with my idea. So, please give me suggestions which will be better - Native app or web app? Also, if you could share some stats or links to justify your suggestion, it would be great.

Comment: Have you tried searching the archives? There have been a few other questions about native vs. web applications for mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is more of an application than website.

Then it should be written as an application rather than a website.

The only reason I can think of for going the web site route would be if you had to support multiple operating systems (iOS, Android, Windows) immediately. If your customers primarily use iPads (for example) then develop the iOS version first, with the other versions following in order of importance.

Having a native application will give the user a better experience and you can make use of the tablet's features.

Your other points in the question simply confirm that this is the correct solution.